# Query Pages using REST

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, rest, pages

I've developed a newsfeed app part that currently gets its information from a list, however we're keen to have article pages that we can click through too.

So far I've not found anything in the REST API to access pages or their content, is this doable via REST or do we need to stick to lists?

Thanks, Ben

Comment: access pages? What do you need exactly?

Comment: We're looking to create article pages, so we'd want to be able to query the page to pull back the title of the page, as well as some other custom fields we would add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting the pages you could utilize the same REST endpoint that is used for getting List Items, for example: `http://<site url>/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)`

JavaScript Example

```
function getListItem(webUrl,listName,listItemId, complete, failure) 
{    
    $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")",   
       type: "GET",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }, 
       success: function (data) {           
           complete(data.d);   
       },      
       error: function (data) {            
           failure(data);    
       }  
    });
}
```

**Usage**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve the page and print its properties:

```
getListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Pages',2,printPageDetails,logError);

function printPageDetails(pageItem)
{
    console.log('Page Content: ' + pageItem.PublishingPageContent);
    console.log('Page Title: ' + pageItem.Title);
}

function logError(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm having a small issue with the results of '/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/Items' whereby it's only pulling back two objects, one is a valid article and the other is returning 'Page not found'. However, there are five pages in the library - what would cause SharePoint to only return one?

Comment: Ignore the above, I'm being completely stupid, was looking at the 'Site Pages' library while querying the 'Pages' library.